# How does MVC architecture based URLs aid search engines to optimize searches

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, url, search

How does MVC architecture based URLs aid search engines to optimize searches.

ASP.NET MVC urls follow different pattern compared with the web forms URL pattern. I see this listed as an advantage for search engines to obtain results. I am not able to understand how though.

There are questions on optimization but that is not what i am trying to ask.

Comment: To really understand how MVC urls are search engine friendly. You need to understand w[hat is a search engine friendly URL](http://searchengineland.com/seo-friendly-url-syntax-practices-134218) I hope this could help.

Answer (score -1):

this is pretty self-explanatory.

hxxp://www.yourdomain.com/buy/shoes/1337/all-stars/black/vintage

just works better than

hxxp://www.yourdomain.com/buy.aspx?id=1337&cat=5&variant=37

You don't really need an MVC framework to do this tough. URL rewrite can do a lot for you.

A well constructed MVC app will typically have a much more logical sitemap when you look at the urls on different levels.